# What's wrong with my Lisp code?

Tags: common-lisp

I have some lisp code that I have to write multiple different ways. I've tried two different ways and I'm unsure of why they don't work. The function has to take a list and return only integers in that list. The first one has to take a map function and the second one has to use loop. This is in Clisp.

Here is my code.

```lisp
(defun posint1 (l)
  (mapcan #'(lambda (x)
              (and (integerp x)
                   (list l)))))
```

and

```lisp
(defun posint1 (l)
  (loop for x in (list l)
        when (integerp x)
        collect x)
  (format t "~A " x))))
```

Comment: 1. Why do you call `list` on `l` which already _is_ a list?  2.Check the number of arguments to `mapcan`.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to fix the first one do to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mapcan`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) requires at least one list argument and you have supplied none in your first function (I can't use names since you call both the same)

The second function tried to format a variable, `x`, that does not exist in that scope. In `loop` x are the one element in `(list l)` which probably should just be `l` since making a one number list doesn't really need iteration. Perhaps you wanted something like:

```
(defun print-integers (list)
  (loop :for x :in list
        :when (integerp x)
        :collect x :into result
        :finally (format t "~A " result)))

;; or using the result as argument
(defun print-integers (list)
  (format t
          "~A "
          (loop :for x :in list
                :when (integerp x)
                :collect x)))

(print-integers '(-1 0.5 1/3 +inf.0 9)) ; ==> NIL (prints (-1 9)
```

Also notice that `integerp` works for whole numbers, also negative ones. The name hinted that you might want to use `(and (integerp x) (>= x 0))` instead.

Comment: This worked for me and I understand the logic behind it. My only question, which might be dumb, is about syntax. Why doesn't when, collect, and finally get parenthesis?

Comment: @user2161813 **LOOP** is a *macro*.  Under the hood, there's a macroexpansion function that's called with all the stuff within the LOOP form, and it translates it into code that can actually be run.  Since that transformation occurs, the stuff inside LOOP doesn't have to have the same syntax as typical code. Try `(macroexpand-1 '(loop for x from 1 to 10 collect x))` to see what kind of transformations happen.

Comment: @user2161813 It's just a design choice. The different lisp versions made `loop` macros and interlisp was first with `for`, but the most copied features was MacLisps `loop` which was adopted by the Lisp Machine lisps. Since it was most common it made the standard. There is an [`iterate`](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) macro that is just like `loop` but with more lispy look. Which is best is a matter of taste :-)